# Example OOP with PHP for Database Connection in Real World

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo, database-connection

Currently i'm learning OOP with PHP. i learn many concept from The Book "OOP with PHP5", published by PACKT, but i want learn from real/good sample for Database connection using PDO and how to write better OOP that implement Design Pattern, Iterator, etc.

**How to do the right and professional way?**

may be if i have table user(user_id, user_name, password, join_time)
There will be a User Class, but i want to know the real sample to wrap the OOP concept using design patter and PDO(one connection file that can used by other class).

Is there any body can give me link or tutorial or sample to learn, a complete set.

Hope any body can understand my english :)

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are beautiful, brilliant things - **when used where needed.**

You should recognize a need for a design pattern by your application and THEN implement it - and not the other way round.

If you are interested in best practices for writing DB adapters, classes etc... You should take a look at the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest). Take a look at how they solved the issues you want to solve.

And don't force the patterns if you don't need them. :)

Cheers,

Comment: I like your statement "don't force the patterns if you don't need them". currently i'm working with many table, i i think there is a smart way to code :). Thanks for your suggestion to use Zend Framework. but i don't want use any framework

Comment: On, I didn't think you should USE it, just look at the way they solved the DB adapters and steal some ideas! If you like the way they handle db connections etc, you can make your own copy / version / upgrade of it. There iz Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysql_Pdo - http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Db/Adapter/Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql.html so take a look. :)

Comment: Thanks, you right, if i like, i can use their way to solve my problem. It's a good idea